# Create a calculated column in SQL using CASE WHEN and IN

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, toad-data-point

How can I create a new set of columns that searches a row for specific codes and flags a Yes or No based on the search criteria in Oracle SQL and MySQL?

Background:

I have a Customer code table that contains ~20+ columns with codes associated with the CustomerID record.  Unfortunately, the columns are not tied to a specific code, as a result, each column can contain any code.

```
Customer Code 

CustomerID |col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|...|col20|
-----------------------------------------------
A          | 0   |  0 |  10| 19 | 200|...| 50 |
B          | 1   | 5  | 19 | 0  | 50 |...| 8  |
...
```

The goal is to create a subquery that contains several columns with the Customer ID that will indicate if the Customer has a specific code associated with them.  For example, create a Code 10, Code 19, and Code 5 column and flag is as "Y" for each CustomerID if they have a code 10, 19, or 5  in any of the 20 columns in the table,

The result would look something like this.. (new columns in bold)

```
CustomerID |col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|...|col20| **Code 10**| **Code 19** | **Code 5**
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A          | 0   |  0 |  10| 19 | 200|...| 50 |  **Y**     |    **Y**    | **N**
B          | 1   | 5  | 19 | 0  | 50 |...| 8  |  **N**     |    **Y**    | **Y**
...
```

Current Process that works in Excel:
In Excel, I would create a new column called "All Codes" and concatenate all the columns containing codes.

The new column would look like this:

```
|      All Codes      |
----------------------
|0 0 10 19 200 ... 50 | 
|1 5 19 0  50   ... 8 |
```

After creating a concatenate helper column, I then create a new column for each code I need using an if and contain text function.  Results would look like below:

```
|    All Codes        | Code 10 | Code 19 | Code 5 
-------------------------------------------------------
|0 0 10 19 200 ... 50 |  Y      |  Y      | N
|1 5 19 0  50   ... 8 |  N      |  Y      | Y
```

Then I would remove the All Codes and join the new table with the CustomerID table.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Normalize your data.

Comment: What does 'contains ~20+ columns' are the number of columns fixed or not?

Comment: Yep, seriously consider revising your schema

Comment: Thanks guys, and I really appreciate your suggestions!  The data architecture was poorly designed and unfortunately, I am stuck with this scrappy data.  Columns are fixed at 24 but there are more than 50 codes.  (stopped counting after 50).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` and `in`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when 10 in (col1, col2, . . .)
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as cod_10,
       (case when 19 in (col1, col2, . . .)
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as cod_19,
       (case when 5 in (col1, col2, . . .)
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as cod_5
from t;
```

The `. . .` is for the rest of the code columns.

This is standard SQL and should work in any database.

I would recommend that you change the data structure.  You should have a table with one row per `customerId` and `code`, a `customerCodes` table.

Answer (score 1):

On your denormalized structure you may use something like

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, CONCAT_WS(',', col1, col2, ... , col20) total
              FROM source_table )
SELECT *, CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(10, total) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Code10
FROM cte
```

Comment: The cure is worse than the disease

Comment: @Strawberry Agreed. But as a temporary solution, until data normalization is completed, it will do.

Comment: There's no such thing as temporary

Comment: @Strawberry Nothing is more permanent than temporary?

Comment: @Akina  Thanks!  I'll test this out in the morning.  I appreciate it!